# hasClass if statement for navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, if-statement, gallery

first post here so bear with me!

I am using the jquery ui tabs plugin to create a gallery and i want to have a little arrow slide left and right to show the user which gallery is being shown:

the code i'm using is this:

```
<script>
if ($('#wedding-btn').hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
    $('.nav-selector').css('left', '5px');
} else if ($('#portrait-btn').hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
    $('.nav-selector').css('left', '125px');
} else if ($('#landscape-btn').hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
    $('.nav-selector').css('left', '255px');
} else if ($('#blackandwhite-btn').hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
    $('.nav-selector').css('left', '410px');
}   
</script>
```

here is a link to show what i'm talking about:
http://www.maxhenchman.co.uk/oh/latest2/

I've looked at some other articles on here and the code above seems like it should work...but i'm pretty new to jquery so i'm probably wrong.

any help would be great!

Thanks,

Max

EDIT for johnny:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            show: { effect: "fade", duration: 400 },
            hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 800 }
        });

    });

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#wedding-btn').click(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-active'))
                        $('.nav-selector').css('left', '5px');
                });

            $('#portrait-btn').click(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-active'))
                        $('.nav-selector').css('left', '125px');
                });

            $('#landscape-btn').click(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-active'))
                        $('.nav-selector').css('left', '255px');
                });

            $('#blackandwhite-btn').click(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass('ui-state-active'))
                        $('.nav-selector').css('left', '410px');
                });

            });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my final answer, since you need a delay I wrapped the classcheck into a function and called it on .click() with a delay using setTimeout. Here the code:

```
    function check_location(){

        if ($('#wedding-btn').hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
            $('.nav-selector').css('left', '5px');
        } else if ($('#portrait-btn').hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
            $('.nav-selector').css('left', '125px');
        } else if ($('#landscape-btn').hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
            $('.nav-selector').css('left', '255px');
        } else if ($('#blackandwhite-btn').hasClass('ui-state-active')) {
            $('.nav-selector').css('left', '410px');
        }

    }

    $('#tabs').click(function(){

        setTimeout(check_location,1000)

    });
```

Comment: Ah sorry, i edited before seeing your reply - it's now using that code and it's still not working, any ideas?

Comment: updated the code, should work, tested it on your page with firebug

Comment: Ok i've added your code... it works but now the selector is always one step behind... i think it's because it's firing before the new 'active' class is set. i can't think of a way around this... unless i could delay it?

Comment: updated the code, works better then onclick and no step behinde :)

Comment: just realized that the code is now the same that Lukas has posted.. anyway for me it's working on your site.

Comment: right ok, where should it be written in relation to the tabs script? because the way i have it set up, the arrow only moves if you click again after the animation has finished.

(refresh the site to see what i mean)

i've edited the original post to show how i have it set up.

Comment: Yay! thanks a lot, sorry i was terrible at explaining it all.

Comment: We found a solution, that counts! :D

Answer (score 1):

I reworked the code and made up a solution which does things properly by using the `activate` event of the tabs widget:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            show: { effect: "fade", duration: 400 },
            hide: { effect: "fade", duration: 400 },
            activate: function(event, ui) {
                tab = ui.newTab;

                if(tab.is('#wedding-btn'))
                    $('.nav-selector').css('left', '5px');

                else if(tab.is('#portrait-btn'))
                    $('.nav-selector').css('left', '125px');

                else if(tab.is('#landscape-btn'))
                    $('.nav-selector').css('left', '255px');

                else if(tab.is('#blackandwhite-btn'))
                    $('.nav-selector').css('left', '410px');

            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Remove everything regarding your tabs issue and try this one.

Comment: Yes, what i commented out is what i used before - which works but the way jqueryui tabs works, it only lets you change tabs once the animation is completed.... meaning that if you click between the tabs too fast, the arrow jumps but the tabs don't change because the animation is not complete. hope that makes sense.

Comment: @MaxHenchman I combined both the existing code with the `if` condition. Have a look at the resulting code.

Comment: The problem is the same as the other replies suggestion - the <li> doesn't have the active class when the button is first clicked because of the animation... so it only moves the arrow if you click again after the tab has changed. how can i delay the arrow code from firing instantly?

Comment: Well, I'm a perfectionist... here's another solution using the `activate` event of the tabs widget which _should_ exactly be what you need.